# Pdf of sum of triangular distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $U_a$ and $U_b$ be independent random variables with uniform distribution over $(0,1)$. Then $Y:=U_a-U_b$ has triangular distribution with density

$$
f_Y(x) = (1+x)\mathsf 1_{(-1,0)}(x) + (1-x)\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(x).
$$

Now let $Y_i$, $i=1,2,\ldots$ be i.i.d. with the above distribution. What is the distribution of $X_n:= \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a nice closed form for the density of $X_n$. Even for $n=2$, there are four cases to consider for integral bounds for the convolution, and the result ends up being
$$
f_{X_2}(t) = \frac16(8+12t+6t^2+t^3)\mathsf 1_{(-2,1)}(t) + \frac16(4-6t^2-3t^3)\mathsf 1_{(-1,0)}(t) + \frac16(4-6t^2+3t^3)\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(t) + \frac16(8-12t+6t^2-t^3)\mathsf 1_{(1,2)}(t).
$$
So in general, the density of $X_n$ is going to be a piecewise polynomial of degree $n+1$ over $(-n,-n+1),\ldots,(n-1,n)$. We can, however, find the characteristic function of $X_n$. First we compute
\begin{align}
\varphi_Y(\theta) :&= \mathbb E[e^{i\theta Y}]\\
&= \int_{-1}^0 e^{i\theta t}(1+t)\ \mathsf dt + \int_0^1 e^{i\theta t}(1-t)\ \mathsf dt\\
&= -\frac{e^{-i \theta } \left(1-e^{i \theta }\right)^2}{\theta ^2}.
\end{align}
Since the characteristic function of the sum of independent random variables is the product of their characteristic functions, it follows that
\begin{align}
\varphi_{X_n}(\theta) :&= \mathbb E[e^{i\theta X_n}]\\
&= \mathbb E[e^{i\theta\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}]\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[e^{i\theta Y_i}]\\
&= (\mathbb E[e^{i\theta Y}])^n\\
&= \left(-\frac{e^{-i \theta } \left(1-e^{i \theta }\right)^2}{\theta ^2}\right)^n.
\end{align}

Comment: There's a wiki describing the closed form solution of Irwin-Hall distribution (Sum of standard uniform distribution) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution. I'm not sure if this helps, but as n grows larger, the sum of standard triangular distribution tends to follow N(0, n*2/12), according to Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: @AngYiwei This post is asking about the sum of triangular distributions, not the sum of uniform distributions.